# Which Jackson maven dependencies to include in spring 3.1 project for JAXB JSON marshalling?

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb, marshalling

In the code sample available [here](http://sleeplessinslc.blogspot.nl/2012/01/spring-31-mvc-example.html), one imports the following for JSON JAXB marshalling:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Yet, [this](http://hillert.blogspot.nl/2011/01/marshal-json-data-using-jackson-in.html) blog post, referring to [this](http://ondra.zizka.cz/stranky/programovani/java/jaxb-json-jackson-howto.texy) blog post, suggests:

```xml
<!-- Jackson -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-lgpl</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

where 'jackson-xc provides the additional Jaxb support'.

What is the difference between both set of maven dependencies when it comes to JAXB JSON marhsalling in Spring? Which one should be used preferably?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main difference i can see is the license.

The first option uses `jackson-mapper-asl` which uses the apache license, while the second one uses the lgpl license. so it is really a matter of legal.

see [here](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonDownload).

Answer (score 1):

Use this dependency in your pom.xml file.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
    </dependency>
```